# Performance monitoring for Google Cloud DataProc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We are using GoogleCloudPlatform for big-data analytics.
For processing we are currently using the google cloud dataproc & spark-streaming.

We would like to check the job performance using some monitoring utilities like Ganglia, Graphite, Dr.Elephant etc.

For setting up of any of these requires modification of configuration in each nodes.
I would like to know, if the dataproc natively supports any of such performance monitoring tools?

Answer (score 3):

None of those are supported out of the box, but you could add Ganglia using [this initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/ganglia). You can configure it however you like by editing the script.

You would then have to follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/cluster-web-interfaces) to access the Web UI.