Identifying Idle Executors in Spark Application Using Event Logs
How can I identify idle executors in a Spark application using Spark event logs stored in separate tables for metrics like executor, task, etc.? Specifically, I have observed that some executors have zero values for total tasks, completed tasks, and total duration. In contrast, other executors have the same values for these metrics. Does this discrepancy indicate that a portion of the executors are idle, presenting an opportunity for right-sizing?
Am trying to optimize the spark jobs (right sizing the dataproc cluster) by analysing spark event logs.

You can start a cluster with ganglia monitoring tools. EMR has ganglia as an appliction. Similarly dataproc must also have such a tool. Check in your documentation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37794255/3238085

Thanks @user238607. Generally speaking we can check the idle executors in spark event log ? and update the spark config
